# Auto resize image in CSS

Tags: html, css

How to auto re size my image, If I change my width and length to auto it won't able to display any image. My image will overlapping the text when I re-size my browser so, I would like to change my image size to dynamic.

**HTML source**

```
<div class="span2">
   <ul class="nav user_menu pull-left">
     <div class="round-pic1" style="background-image: url('http://asianwiki.com/images/a/a4/Andy-lau.jpg');"></div>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.round-pic1 {
 display: block;
 width: 170px;
 height: 170px;
 margin: 0em auto;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
 border-radius: 99em;
 -webkit-border-radius: 99em;
 -moz-border-radius: 99em;
 border: 0px solid gray;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/9JVHq/

Comment: Div's `height:auto` means that its height is based on the content inside it. In your code, there's nothing inside so the height is 0px. Instead of using div, try <img>.

Comment: It work in `img` but when I try to resize my browser image will become oval.

Comment: I think you need to use `max-width` and `max-height`.

Comment: Cannot use `max-width` and `max-height`, once used image cannot display.

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing around with your fiddle a bit and have come up with a potential solution here - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9JVHq/6/).

1. Make your picture square and put it in the code as an image.
2. Put the image in a div and give the div a min-width and max-width.

It allows the image to shrink down to 100px, keeping the same aspect ratio.
Let me know if that's what your looking for.

CSS

```
.holder {
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 300px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class='holder'>
    <img class="round-pic1" src='http://offsite2.seriousshops.com/53/11/11635/11635_main_400x400.jpg'/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using  this one css to resize bg image:

jsfiddle.net/YCtDr/

> background-size: 100% 100%;

[MOre info](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-background-size-property/)

```
   If you want to preserve aspect ratio, there are two more possibilities.

     1. background-size: cover; - the background image is completely
        covering the element (image can be cut off)

     2.background-size: contain; - the image is streched without cutting it
```